# Connection drops if I don't ping server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping, modem

I have trouble, for several months now, but I never cared asking anyone why this keeps happening. Basically if I try to reach my Server in my LAN-Network, I need to ping it several times in a row, until it "engages" (Like an old car)...
The connection keeps stable while I am pinging, but if I stop, the connection will get slower and starts dropping (Timeout and such stuff).

Here what my command prompt looks like (It's not in english, but I think the command below is familiar to everyone here):

```
C:\Users\Username>ping 192.168.8.50 -t

Disparando 192.168.8.50 com 32 bytes de dados:
Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=11ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=1ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=1ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=2ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=26ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=1ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=1ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=1ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=1ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=1ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=4ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=1ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=1ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=1ms TTL=63
Resposta de 192.168.8.50: bytes=32 tempo=1ms TTL=63
[... Keeps stable connection, until I stop pinging]
```

I need to do this everytime I want to work with my server. I keep this window in the background pinging, but that's somewhat annoying and I can't explain myself why this is happening...
I tried with several different routers (TP-Link [Stock, OpenWrt, DD-Wrt], D-Link, ...). All those present the exact same behaviour.

My LAN network looks like this:

[image: LAN Network]

I also tried to disable the Firewall of the router entirely and nothing changed.
I can't be the only one who has this problem...

Comment: Likely an issue related to the double NAT here. Have you tried connecting the server directly to the router instead of to the modem?

Comment: @allquicatic Yeah, If I connect it on the red portion (192.168.8.x) of the network, it works normally...

Comment: Err, isn't it *already* connected to the "red portion of the network"? I meant directly connecting the server to a LAN port of "ROUTER" -- this would give it an IP in the 192.168.17.x range assuming your netmask is 255.255.255.0.

Comment: Anyway, one thing you could try is configuring "ROUTER" box (whatever it is) to do layer 2 switching rather than layer 3 routing. By making the router an Ethernet switch and effectively disabling its layer 3 IP functionality, your entire network will be on a unified IP subnet - namely, the one from the modem, 192.168.8.x (probably netmask 255.255.255.0). This resolves the unnecessary complexity of double NAT. The exact steps to do it will depend on what software your router is running, and since you didn't state it, I can only guess at it.

Comment: `I meant directly connecting the server to a LAN port of "ROUTER" -- this would give it an IP in the 192.168.17.x range assuming your netmask is 255.255.255.0` @allquicatic That should work, but since both routers are far away, that's not possible... The cables don't reach.

Comment: @allquicatic The "ROUTER" is a "d-link ac3200"

Comment: @allquicatic http://prntscr.com/da0v20

Comment: I guess you'll have to figure out how to disable the NAT / revert to a simple Layer 2 switch on your own, as I'm not familiar with that model. Just poke around in the settings and see what it lets you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been some years since I posted this question and I just stumbled at it again while looking at my questions in my profile.

I remember this problem and I solved it some days later, but totally forgot to answer it here.

The problem was that the Subnet Mask was incorrect on **one** of these routers/modems. If I remember right, it was `255.255.0.0` instead of `255.255.255.0` and while pinging it would force the right Subnet-Mask or something like that.